# logical consequence that is not tautological

Tags: logic

I am told that every tautological consequence is also a logical consequence, but what would a **simple** example be of a logical consequence that is *not* a tautological consequence?

**Update**
To further explain what I have

1. $Q$ is a *tautological consequence* of $P_1...P_n$ if and only if every row that assigns $True$ to each of $P_1...P_n$ also assigns $True$ to $Q$
2. If $Q$ is a *tautological consequence* of $P_1...P_n$ then $Q$ is also a *logical consequence* of $P_1...P_n$
3. Some *logical consequences* are not *tautological consequences*.

I understand on how to see if $Q$ is a tautological consequence from a truth-table but not sure on how to know if it is a logical consequence in the absence of a tautological one.

Comment: And what do you mean by logical consequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation only arises in first-order logic, not propositional logic. One formula is a tautological consequence of another if the two formulas arise by substituting first-order formulas into propositional formulas, so that the first propositional formula implies the second in propositional logic.

For example, the formula
$$
A \land (A \to B)
$$
implies the formula
$$B \lor C$$
in propositional logic. Thus the first-order formula
$$
(\forall x) S(x) \lor (\exists x) R(x)
$$
is a tautological consequence of the formula
$$
(\exists x)P(x) \land [(\exists x)P(x) \to (\forall x)S(x)].
$$
These are obtained by replacing the letters $A$, $B$, and $C$ with particular first-order formulas.

On the other hand, there are some logical implications in first-order logic that do not arise in this way. These implications tend to involve quantifier rules. For example, $(\exists x)S(x)$ is a logical consequence of $(\forall x)S(x)$ in first-order logic, but not a tautological consequence. Similarly $(\forall x)S(x)$ is a logical consequence of $(\forall y)S(y)$ but not a tautological consequence.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you speak about first order logic an by **tautological consequence** you mean e.g.

$$P(x)\wedge P(y)\models P(x),$$

in other word something that follows propositionally. And **logical consequence** would be e.g.

$$\forall x P(x)\models P(x),$$

where the inference involves quantifiers. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Updated question